# Find 'template page' in Google and fill in with POST/GET

Tags: php, html, post, get, seo

I'm making a real estate website and I want every building in my database to be found by search engines. Now, do I have to generate a new **static** page each time I submit a building to my database or can I make google immediately search my database and use **POST or GET** to fill in my template page so the building gets displayed the same way as a static page?

Static example: http://www.real-estate.com/offices/offices-opera-house-sydney

POST example: http://www.real-estate.com?offices=O-123

If there is any other way of doing this please tell me a well!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely want URLs along the scheme of the first pattern, that is true. But you do not have to generate a "static page" for that. At least not what is typically titled as "static page", so a file holding html or similar.

Your issue is not about static or dynamic pages. In fact that is something the bot does not know about. It cannot be "seen" from the outside. The two URLs you gave can lead to exactly the same "page", that is the trick.

The easiest approach for this is using "URL rewriting". There are tons of examples for this on the internet. The details depend on your setup obviously. Mostly they depend on the http server you are using. In case of the typical "apache http server" you want to take a closer look at the "rewriting module" that offers you simple means for URL rewriting: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

The basic idea behind this: you give out only links using the "clean" pattern, so something like the first url you named in your question, not holding any query arguments. Then, when such references are used by making a request to your server, these requests are rewritten, so interpreted and locally changed by your server *prior* to processing them and delivering the result. That way you can use clean URLs whilst working with handy query arguments at the same time.

Example:

1. you hand out a URL like that: `http://www.real-estate.com/offices/offices-opera-house-sydney`, for example by posting the link to a board or by putting it into your site map which is scanned by the google bot.
2. a request is done to your server, so it receives the "question" `/offices/offices-opera-house-sydney`.
3. the rewriting takes care to internally change the question to `/process.php?type=offices&object=opera-house-sydney`
4. now the script `process.php` is called, handed over the arguments named `type` and `object` and the output is returned as answer to the browser.

In effect, your servers pages looks like a a tree of "static pages".

An example for the rewriting rules required for this is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/\/([^/]+)\/(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ /process.php?type=%1&object=%2 [L]
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```

As said, the details obviously strongly depend on your specific setup. This example is only meant to set you on the right track. You will be able to find your way from here using a little internet research, existing answers here on SO and a few tries.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was exactly what I was looking for! But this won't influence my SEO in a bad way? Or rather in a good way?

Comment: Well, without this your dynamic pages won't get considered at all by typical bots. So there is not really any way to influence it in a bad way, is there? And as said: a bot cannot tell what you are doing internally anyway. The only thing you have to keep in mind: always use the "clean" URLs, be it in your sitemap or when posting URLs.

Comment: I there a way to regenerate my sitemap everytime I add a building to the database. So that my sitemap gets updated and the url is added to it? In other words a dynamic 'updatable sitemap'.

Comment: Sure there is, that is what is typically done. But as said: that obviously depends on your setup. You gave no clue what base you are implementing your pages on. Typical CMS systems for example come with sitemap modules that exactly what you asked. They collect all known pages from their database,  create a fresh sitemap and upload it to google. If you implement your own logic then you probably want to implement a small script generating a new sitemap each time you add an object. That's not really complicated, in the end the sitemap is just a list of URLs.